# How do I watch movies and shows on my laptop using Ubuntu TV?

Tags: ubuntu-tv

I compiled and in installed Ubuntu TV using [ubuntu-tv/wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing) site. When I run it, though, it can't play TV Shows. It says

```
unity-2d-shell: [WARNING] GStreamer; Unable to play -
    "file:///home/ubuntu/Videos/unity/local/epg/epg.mkv
```

I am assuming that I need an epg file. I have also tried running `~/ubuntu-tv/shell/dash/epgdata/refreshdata.py` but with no luck.

Does Ubuntu TV need to be a "TV" to watch movies and shows? What's going on?

Comment: i havent installed it yet but i'm using XBMC and its awesome

here is a little video i made for my buddies to decide!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7Yl-V_PHcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to watch tv you'll need a compatible DVB-T tuner for your computer in order to capture video and read the electronic program guide (epg). http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Video_capture_card

By the way there is a ppa for ubuntu tv here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-from-ppa.html